# How to retrieve data from a post request

Tags: node.js, express

I have a post request where i intend to update a field after retrieving the current value.

I am attempting to update the field in mongodb. The field is boolean data type.

```
router.route('/books/update/:id').post((req, res) => {
Book.find({ id: parseInt(req.params.id) }, (err, books) => {
    if (!books)
        return next(new Error("Could not load book!"))
    else {
        console.log(books);
        console.log(req.body);
        // let book = new Book(req.body);
        // console.log('Before ', book.title);
        // book.completed = !book.completed
        // console.log('After ', book.completed);

        // book.save().then(book => {
        //     res.json("Update done.");
        // }).catch(err => {
        //     res.status(400).send('Update failed');
        // })
    }
});
});
```

I am using Postman and the data i am passing in the body is,

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "title" : "Read Romeo And Juliet",
    "completed" : false
}
```

I can view the json resultset when I `console.log (books)`. The request `req.body` is blank. Why would that be? As you can see in the commented code I am attempting to set the completed field and update it back to the collection. What would be the best way to go about this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There might a couple of reasons for it. First of all, if it's an express app, make sure that you have some body parsing middleware to parse the body of the http request into a valid js object (JSON if you like). For example, the most popular nowadays is [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser). If it is installed and properly configured, make sure that you request has a "Content-Type" header set to "application/json" in your Postman request headers section. Good luck!

```
// create application/json parser
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
```

Comment: Thank you Vladyslav. I have the body-Parser in my project already. I just managed to get it to work now, I will post the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I used the updateOne function on the Book model,

```
router.route('/books/update/:id').post((req, res) => {

    bookId = parseInt(req.params.id);

    Book.findOne({ id: bookId }, (err, book) => {
        if (!book)
            return next(new Error("Could not load book!"))
        else {
            let book = new Book(req.body);
            book.completed = !book.completed

            Book.updateOne({ id: bookId }, { "completed": book.completed }, function (err, raw) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                }
                else {
                    res.json("Update done.");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```